# How do I get each office to print on a seperate page using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the below xml and xslt.

All the data in the xml file prints on a single page.

Each office has personnel and fax machines associated with them.

I want each office (Office One, Office Two and Office Three) along with their associated personnel and faxes to each print on separate pages.

Thanks in advance for any help.

personnel_roster.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type = "text/xsl" href = "personnel_roster.xslt"?>
<rows appMode="{appmode}" dateGenerated="11/05/2018">
  <row OfficeID="32" OfficeOutputOrder="1" Office="O1" OfficeTitle="Office One" RoomFaxID="88" RoomFaxNumber="(555) 555-1212" RoomNumberID="120">
    <personnel>
      <person PersonnelID="360" Name="Employee Supervisor" PositionRoomNumberID="120" phone="(555) 637-5770" PAETitle="Dir, Head Office" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="1" />
      <person PersonnelID="850" Name="Employee One" PositionRoomNumberID="120" phone="(555) 694-7191" PAETitle="Principal Deputy Director" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="2" />
      <person PersonnelID="669" Name="Employee Two" PositionRoomNumberID="120" phone="(555) 554-0199" PAETitle="Senior Assistant" PositionEmployeeTypeID="M" PositionOutputOrder="11" />
      <person PersonnelID="417" Name="Employee Three" PositionRoomNumberID="125" phone="(555) 336-4242" PAETitle="Special Assistant" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="21" />
      <person PersonnelID="470" Name="Employee Four" PositionRoomNumberID="125" phone="(555) 587-9046" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="21" />
      <person PersonnelID="474" Name="Employee Five" PositionRoomNumberID="125" phone="(555) 2270-8654" PAETitle="Special Assistant to the Director" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="22" />
    </personnel>
    <officeFaxes>
      <fax RoomNumberID="120" RoomFaxNumber="(555) 614-8413" OfficeID="32" />
    </officeFaxes>
  </row>
  <row OfficeID="82" OfficeOutputOrder="5" Office="O2" OfficeTitle="Office Two" RoomFaxID="94" RoomFaxNumber="(555) 555-1213" RoomNumberID="121">
    <personnel>
      <person PersonnelID="582" Name="Employee Supervisor" PositionRoomNumberID="121" phone="(555) 693-7828" PAETitle="Director (O2)" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="4" />
      <person PersonnelID="398" Name="Employee One" PositionRoomNumberID="126" phone="(555) 372-4329" PAETitle="T  Specialist" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="338" Name="Employee Two" PositionRoomNumberID="121" phone="(555) 693-7825" PAETitle="Operations Research Analyst" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="368" Name="Employee Three" PositionRoomNumberID="121" phone="(555) 693-2086" PAETitle="Operations Research Analyst" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="365" Name="Employee Four" PositionRoomNumberID="121" phone="(555) 697-0223" PAETitle="Operations Research Analyst" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="375" Name="Employee Five" PositionRoomNumberID="121" phone="(555) 693-4141" PAETitle="Operations Research Analyst" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="797" Name="Employee Six" PositionRoomNumberID="121" phone="(555) 614-9271" PAETitle="Operations Research Analyst" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="356" Name="Employee Seven" PositionRoomNumberID="121" phone="(555) 697-0361" PAETitle="Operations Research Analyst" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="404" Name="Employee Eight" PositionRoomNumberID="126" phone="(555) 372-4331" PAETitle="manager" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
    </personnel>
    <officeFaxes>
      <fax RoomNumberID="121" RoomFaxNumber="(555) 372-4342" OfficeID="82" />
      <fax RoomNumberID="121" RoomFaxNumber="(555) 372-4370" OfficeID="82" />
      <fax RoomNumberID="126" RoomFaxNumber="(555) 614-8413" OfficeID="82" />
    </officeFaxes>
  </row>
  <row OfficeID="76" OfficeOutputOrder="9" Office="O3" OfficeTitle="Office Three"  RoomFaxID="95" RoomFaxNumber="(555) 555-1214" RoomNumberID="122">
    <personnel>
      <person PersonnelID="763" Name="Employee Supervisor" PositionRoomNumberID="122" phone="(555) 697-9189" PAETitle="Director (O3)" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="4" />
      <person PersonnelID="471" Name="Employee One" PositionRoomNumberID="122" phone="(555) 695-7935" PAETitle="Management and Program Analyst" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="439" Name="Employee Two" PositionRoomNumberID="122" phone="(555) 614-3951" PAETitle="administrative Program Specialist" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="446" Name="Employee Three" PositionRoomNumberID="122" phone="(555) 256-0636" PAETitle="Security Specialist" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="456" Name="Employee Four" PositionRoomNumberID="122" phone="(555) 256-0603" PAETitle="Management and Program Analyst" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="436" Name="Employee Five" PositionRoomNumberID="122" phone="(555) 695-8225" PAETitle="Talent Management Specialist" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
      <person PersonnelID="729" Name="Employee Six" PositionRoomNumberID="122" phone="(555) 693-3038" PAETitle="Administrative Program Specialist (Facilities)" PositionEmployeeTypeID="C" PositionOutputOrder="20" />
    </personnel>
    <officeFaxes>
      <fax RoomNumberID="122" RoomFaxNumber="(555) 256-1412" OfficeID="76" />
    </officeFaxes>
  </row>
</rows>
```

personnel_roster.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" media-type="text/html"/>


    <xsl:template match="/rows">

        <div class="previewPrintReport">
            <table id="art_report_output" class="tablesorter-blue execTable" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="0">
                <caption style="text-align:center;vertical-align:middle"><b>REPORT TITLE </b>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="@appMode='prod'"></xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>&#160;(<xsl:value-of select="@appMode"/>)</xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    generated on <xsl:value-of select="@dateGenerated"/>
                </caption>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4" style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: center;">TELEPHONE ROSTER</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="4" style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: center;">OFFICE OF THE DIRECTOR, COST ASSESSMENT PROGRAM EVALUATION</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="25%">&#160;</th>
                        <th width="30%">&#160;</th>
                        <th width="15%">ROOM NO.</th>
                        <th width="30%">EXTENSION</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <xsl:for-each select="row">

                        <xsl:variable name="officeName" select="@Office"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="officeTitle" select="@OfficeTitle"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="officeFaxRoom" select="@RoomNumberID"/>
                        <xsl:variable name="officeFax" select="@RoomFaxNumber"/>
                        <xsl:variable name ="officeFirst" select="/rows/row[1]/@Office"/>
                        <xsl:variable name ="officeLast" select="/rows/row[last()]/@Office"/>

                        <xsl:if test="personnel">
                            <page>
                            <xsl:element name="tr">
                                <td colspan="4"><hr style="background-color: #000000;" /></td>
                            </xsl:element>

                            <xsl:for-each select="personnel/person">
                                <xsl:choose>
                                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                                        <!-- Office Manager -->
                                        <xsl:element name="tr">
                                            <td>Director (<xsl:value-of select="$officeName"/>)<br/><xsl:value-of select="$officeTitle"/></td>
                                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
                                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@PositionRoomNumberID"/></td>
                                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@phone"/></td>
                                        </xsl:element>      
                                    </xsl:when>
                                    <xsl:otherwise>
                                        <xsl:element name="tr">
                                            <td>&#160;</td>
                                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@Name"/></td>
                                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@PositionRoomNumberID"/></td>
                                            <td><xsl:value-of select="@phone"/></td>
                                        </xsl:element>
                                    </xsl:otherwise>
                                </xsl:choose>
                            </xsl:for-each>

                            <xsl:if test="officeFaxes">
                                <xsl:element name="tr">
                                    <td>&#160;</td>
                                    <td>&#160;</td>
                                    <td>&#160;</td>
                                    <td>&#160;</td>
                                </xsl:element>

                                <xsl:for-each select="officeFaxes/fax">
                                    <xsl:choose>
                                        <xsl:when test="position()=1 and $officeFax">
                                            <xsl:element name="tr">
                                                <td>&#160;</td>
                                                <td>Fax Line:</td>
                                                <td><xsl:value-of select="$officeFaxRoom"/></td>
                                                <td><xsl:value-of select="$officeFax"/></td>
                                            </xsl:element>                                          
                                            <xsl:element name="tr">
                                                <td>&#160;</td>
                                                <td>&#160;</td>
                                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@RoomNumberID"/></td>
                                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@RoomFaxNumber"/></td>
                                            </xsl:element>
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                                            <xsl:element name="tr">
                                                <td>&#160;</td>
                                                <td>Fax Line:</td>
                                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@RoomNumberID"/></td>
                                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@RoomFaxNumber"/></td>
                                            </xsl:element>                                          
                                        </xsl:when>
                                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                            <xsl:element name="tr">
                                                <td>&#160;</td>
                                                <td>&#160;</td>
                                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@RoomNumberID"/></td>
                                                <td><xsl:value-of select="@RoomFaxNumber"/></td>
                                            </xsl:element>
                                        </xsl:otherwise>
                                    </xsl:choose>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:if>
                            </page>
                            <xsl:if test="$officeName=$officeFirst or $officeName=$officeLast">
                                <xsl:element name="tr">
                                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center; padding-top: 10px;"><span class="importantContactNumber">*** Call Center Support  555-555-1316 ***</span></td>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:if>

                            <xsl:if test="$officeName=$officeLast">
                                <xsl:element name="tr">
                                    <td colspan="4" style="text-align: center;">FOOTER FOR LAST OFFICE</td>
                                </xsl:element>
                            </xsl:if>

                        </xsl:if>                       
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </tbody>

            </table>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: could you please include your desired output in html?

Comment: By " print on separate pages", do you mean you want separate HTML files for each office?

Comment: You probably want to render a separate table for each office, and then use the css property "page-break-before" to specify a page break when printing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a css solution, I gave the row with my separator at the end of each office the following inline style.

```
<tr style="page-break-after: always;">
```